# Batman arkham knight: game stuck at stop Scarecrow from blowing up ACE Chemicals

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-knight

I am playing Batman arkham knight PC version.
I am not able to progress the game beyond the part 5, after rescuing the 4th worker from the ace chemicals. As per the walkthroughs, Upon entering back into the factory area there is supposed to be a cutscene with oracle, after which the wall with ACE chemicals logo is marked and can be broken with the 60mm cannon. But it is not working, I don't see any cutscene with oracle, or the marked wall. does anyone have a patch for this? How do I progress from here?

http://guides.gamepressure.com/batmanarkhamknight/guide.asp?ID=31008

Comment: There should be a 5th worker somewhere that you missed: 1 dead in the hut where you open the gate, 1 on a side building across the pipes (where the Knight does his monologue), 1 right after the gas pipe, 1 right before the elevator and 1 after the elevator. If you did get all 5 workers, then this is a bug and you might have to restore a savegame backup.

Comment: let me check it out

Comment: Since my comment helped you, I posted it as an answer. Could you please upvote and accept it so other people with the same problem know what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer so other people with this issue can also have an idea what to do:

There should be a 5th worker somewhere that you missed: 1 dead in the hut where you open the gate, 1 on a side building across the pipes (where the Knight does his monologue), 1 right after the gas pipe, 1 right before the elevator and 1 after the elevator. If you did get all 5 workers, then this is a bug and you might have to restore a save game backup.

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this game twice. Once in simple story mode and then in new and hard mode. That mission is a tricky one as the whole game is.

You have to be at a specific location for that cutscene to get activated. So try to change your place as the same in the walkthroughs and only see the walkthroughs which are played on pc as this games is slight different then on ps4 and xbox.

So change the place slowly and do not run and you will get passthrough that level easily.